# Append multiindex dataframe in HDF

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

**Following end-of-day stock data as example:**

```
In [36]: df
Out[36]:
        Code                             Name     High      Low    Close  Volume  Change Change.2
0       AAAU     Perth Mint Physical Gold ETF  16.8500  16.3900  16.6900  311400  0.0000     0.02
1       AADR  Advisorshares Dorsey Wright ADR  49.8400  49.2300  49.6100   18500 -1.3000     2.54
2       AAMC                 Altisource Asset  24.0000  20.0000  23.9400    2500  0.3600     1.53
3        AAU                 Almaden Minerals   0.3987   0.3650   0.3684  355100 -0.0147     3.84
4       ABEQ       Absolute Core Strategy ETF  23.2100  22.8200  23.1100  114700 -0.1900     0.82
...      ...                              ...      ...      ...      ...     ...     ...      ...
26643   ZVLO                        Esoft Inc   0.0600   0.0600   0.0600    1000  0.0100       20
26644   ZVTK                      Zevotek Inc   0.0313   0.0209   0.0302   44900  0.0102       51
26645  ZXAIY   China Zenix Auto International   0.1534   0.1534   0.1534     200 -0.1566    50.52
26646   ZYRX            Zyrox Mining Intl Inc   0.0200   0.0181   0.0200    3000  0.0000        0
26647  ZZZOF           Zinc One Resources Inc   0.0111   0.0111   0.0111     300  0.0000        0
```

**Additional question:**

There are some different ways to store this kind of data to HDF5.

1. Don't change the DataFrame and save it with df.to_hdf() to differt
   groups named by date.
2. Split the different stocks to series and build the table by Name or better by 'Code' with the attribute 'Name'
3. Append an multiindex DataFrame in only one group.

I guess the third solution would be the fastest and most flexible in case of data acessing and analyzing. But with the secound solution it seems to be easier to add new information like fundamentals to each company. Is there a better compromise that I don't know yet?

**The main problem (third way):**

I use this code to append the hierachial dataframe on every new day:

```
df = pd.concat(lod, ignore_index=True)

# remove not useful dataj
df = df.drop(['Change.1', 'Change.2', 'Unnamed: 9'], axis=1)
df = df.dropna()

# append a Date column
df['Date'] = dt.datetime.today().date() - dt.timedelta(days=1)

# create multiindex
df = df.set_index(['Date', 'Code', 'Name'])

# append the data to hdf5 container
df.to_hdf(wkd + 'Database.h5', key='stocks', mode='a', format='table')
```

The table is replaced instead of expanded. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my main problem was quite simple:

Fond it here:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4584

Just add 'append = True'

```
df.to_hdf(wkd + 'Database.h5', key='stocks', mode='a', format='table', append = True)
```

Edit:
My current answer to the additional question would be:

I think it's ok to use the third way because it's easy to query the multiindex dataframe with the pandas HDFStore object on disc:

```
store.select('stocks', "Code=BMWYY")
```

To add new data like comany fundamentals i just add a new table object to the HDF file. Then i query both tables and do further analysis with pandas.